# How to write a code to produce a sequence dependent on previous elements

Tags: python

I am trying to complete the following question to create a code for a sequence but am unsure where to begin as I feel the definitions are all dependent on each other? The question is:
Consider the integer sequence defined by

0=1 and, for ≥1
 = the number of values of ∈{0,…,−1} for which  divides −1

The first elements of the sequence are:
1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,3,5…

Write a function named 'dividers_sequence_element' which, given a non-negative integer n, returns

Hint: You may wish to construct a list containing the first +1 elements in the sequence.

Comment: Please, include the code you have write so far and explain why it does not work. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What @Valentino said. We need to see what you've done so far, and ideally an [mcve].